# Windows phone button - adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth equivalent (auto shrink text to button size)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone

Did Windows Phone API contains some equivalent of iOS `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` button parameter? I want text shrink to fit button. I know that it is easy to make button text multiline, but I want to have button always one line height.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Someone build a textblock control with such a property.
So you could use that control and set it as the buttons content.
http://edventuro.us/2010/03/an-auto-scaling-textblock-for-silverlight/
(C# code and example project linked in the last sentence)